# Postgres "unnesting" multiple json arrays simultaneouesly with different depths

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to explode/unnest a row of jsonb arrays into individual rows and keep any rows that would result in nulls.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pgd6E5yKf8NzPtgboeoC6c/7

Input table: (I am stuck with the input being in this form)

| id | name | color | price | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["Banana"] | [["Green"]] | [[[1]]] | [[["Good"]]] |
| 2 | ["Banana"] | [["Yellow"]] | [[[]]] | [[[]]] |
| 3 | ["Apple","Carrot"] | [["Red"],["Orange"]] | [[[10]],[[14]]] | [[["Round"]],[["Long"]]] |
| 4 | ["Grape","Pineapple"] | [["Green"],["Brown","Pink"]] | [[[2]],[[13],[29]]] | [[["Small"]],[["Short"],["Tall"]]] |
| 5 | ["Orange","Potato"] | [["Orange"],["Purple","Brown"]] | [[[2]],[[9],[]]] | [[["Bright"]],[["Gross"],[]]] |

Desired Output:

| id | name | color | price | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | Green | 1 | Good |
| 2 | Banana | Yellow | null | null |
| 3 | Apple | Red | 10 | Round |
| 3 | Carrot | Orange | 14 | Long |
| 4 | Grape | Green | 2 | Small |
| 4 | Pineapple | Brown | 13 | Short |
| 4 | Pineapple | Pink | 29 | Tall |
| 5 | Orange | Orange | 2 | Bright |
| 5 | Potato | Purple | 9 | Gross |
| 5 | Potato | Brown | null | null |

I can get the output I want with this query, but I am trying to generate these queries using a templating engine and I'm trying to account for any number of elements being any depth of nested arrays.  Trying to template this to handle that will be less than ideal.

```
-- Gives expected results
WITH first_level AS (
  SELECT
      id,
      jsonb_array_elements(name) AS name,
      jsonb_array_elements(color) AS color,
      jsonb_array_elements(price) AS price,
      jsonb_array_elements(description) AS description
  FROM food
),
second_level AS (
SELECT
      id,
      name,
      jsonb_array_elements(color) AS color,
      jsonb_array_elements(price) AS price,
      jsonb_array_elements(description) AS description
  FROM first_level
  )
SELECT
      id,
      name,
      color,
      CASE
            WHEN price = '[]'::jsonb THEN null
            ELSE jsonb_array_elements(price)
      END AS price,
      CASE
            WHEN description = '[]'::jsonb THEN null
            ELSE jsonb_array_elements(description)
      END AS description
FROM second_level
```

I've tried unnesting them all at once but with pg 9.6 that gives back a bad result and doesnt have the nulls, It works better on pg10+ but it still drops the rows with empty arrays.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this result? I've run across examples of using lateral joins but none of them are exact matches and I cant figure them out to even get a result close to what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Why Postgres 9.6? It has [reached EOL last year](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Also, your demo with a constant time value is unhelpful. Use a unique id instead.

Comment: 9.6 is just what I am stuck with for now.  It is in the process of being phased out but until that team does it, its what I have to work with.  I made it so the times are not the same though I dont follow the significance.  The input I have to work with doesnt have unique ids.

Comment: For the purpose of this question simple unique IDs are much clearer, your time values only confuse. (Times are the same in your fiddle.)

Comment: Ahh, yeah the timestamps are hard to quickly parse and see the relations.  I updated the question and fiddle to just show ids instead of time. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: An array inside an array inside an array seems like a horrible way to store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnesting multiple set-returning functions in parallel behaved in mysterious ways (borderline broken) in Postgres 9.6. That got fixed with Postgres 10. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)

The same fix also made set-returning functions in a `CASE` construct illegal. Your query only works on account of that superseded behaviour in Postgres 9.6 and breaks in later versions. Same as my simpler rCTE solution:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4d523ba7cedc7a660a1cc7697a2bae32)*

You didn't specify what's allowed in your input format. Making some assumptions, this works in modern Postgres (and in Postgres 9.6, too):

Custom function (accepts non-arrays, too):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(jsonb)
  RETURNS SETOF jsonb
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF jsonb_typeof($1) = 'array' THEN 
      IF $1 = '[]' THEN
         RETURN NEXT jsonb 'null';
      ELSE
         RETURN QUERY SELECT jsonb_array_elements($1);
      END IF;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEXT $1;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Main query (with multiple advanced SQL features):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, 1 AS lvl, ARRAY[ord] AS path, t.*
   FROM   food
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL ROWS FROM (
      f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(name)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(color)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(price)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(description)
      ) WITH ORDINALITY t(n, c, p, d, ord) ON true

   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, lvl + 1, path || t.ord, t.*
   FROM   cte c
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL ROWS FROM (
      f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(n)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(c)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(p)
    , f_jsonb_array_elements_if_any(d)
      ) WITH ORDINALITY t(n, c, p, d, ord) ON true
   WHERE  'array' IN (jsonb_typeof(c.n), jsonb_typeof(c.c), jsonb_typeof(c.p), jsonb_typeof(c.d))
   )
SELECT id, (first_value(n) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp ORDER BY path))->>0 AS name
     , c->>0 AS color, p->>0 AS price, d->>0 AS description
FROM  (
   SELECT count(n) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY path) AS grp, *
   FROM   cte c
   WHERE  lvl = (SELECT max(lvl) FROM cte)
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=83a3320ef6a552ae829da724b18f0578)*

Cycle with a recursive CTE, unnesting arrays until no array is left.

In the outer `SELECT` only use rows from the lat iteration (`max(lvl)`)

Where a single element in `name` was combined with multiple in the other columns, we get genuine `null` values (as opposed to a `jsonb 'null'` from an empty array). Fill in the last actual value for the same group of rows.

Finally extract `text` from the `jsonb` wrapper.

This is one of the rare occasions where a [`ROWS FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) construct is instrumental. See:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860)
- [How to "zip" multiple nested JSON arrays without using id key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798482/939860)

Comment: Thank you, that gets me exactly what I need, Now I just need to learn some new parts of sql so I fully understand what is happening.